# Passing Multidimensional PHP Array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, multidimensional-array

I'm currently transferring a PHP array that is the result of an SQL query into a javascript function but it is not performing properly.

When i attempt to print to error check the json array I have passed it just gives the output of [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], which is obviously not ideal.

```
  <?php


       include_once('connect.php');
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ip, longitude, latitude FROM IPDB;");           

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
$iplonglat[] = array('ip'=>$row['ip'],     'longitude'=>$row['longitude'],     'latitude'=>$row['latitude']);
  }

$jsoniplonglat = json_encode($iplonglat);

?>


    <script type="text/javascript">


var obj = <?php echo $jsoniplonglat; ?>;
document.write(obj);

</script>
```

Comment: Try: `document.write(JSON.stringify(obj))` instead and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON it a multiple dimension array would look like this (for three dimension)

```
"[[[val111, val112],[val121, val122]],[[val211, val212],[val221, val222]]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

To print whole JSON do

```
var _html = JSON.stringify(obj);
    // Now ideally you should do document.getElementById("someidofdiv").innerHTML = _html;
    // or console.log(_html);
    // or document.write(_html);
```

Or for specific values you should be doing

```
var _html = "";
for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
{
_html +=obj[i].ip+"  ";
}
// Now ideally you should do document.getElementById("someidofdiv").innerHTML = _html;
// or console.log(_html);
// or document.write(_html);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $iplonglat[] = array(json_encode('ip'=>$row['ip'])
                     ,json_encode('longitude'=>$row['longitude'])
                     ,json_encode('latitude'=>$row['latitude']));
```